# How to add a linear layer on top of another linear layer?

Tags: pytorch, image-classification

I am training AlexNet. I am using Metric Learning followed by classification. I have created a 64 dimensional embedding. Now I want a linear Layer that I will use for my classification problem. How can I add a Linear layer with five classes?

Model Architecture

[image: 1]

I have tried adding a Linear layer(64,5) but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) Also, if you have some code already, could you show what you have?

Comment: after editing your post. Can you be more specific regarding "that didn't work"?